# Como permitir acesso à página APENAS por formulário

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Tenho uma página no wordpress que existe um formulário, a qual o usuário passa email, nome e estado. Quando a inscrição é completada, eu capturo seus dados numa base (MailChimp, no meu caso) e redireciono para outra página, a qual ele terá acesso a um simulado, por exemplo.

Entretanto, gostaria de que o acesso à essa página redirecionada fosse feito, EXCLUSIVAMENTE, pelo meu formulário descrito.

Pois não quero que haja a possibilidade de digitar na url diretamente o endereço da página redirecionada. Exemplo: dominio.com.br/simulado

Caso o fizesse, ele entraria na home novamente, ou qualquer outra coisa do tipo.
Enfim, como é possível fazer essa restrição?

Comment: Ok, obg! Mas aí volto ao problema inicial (kkkkk). Como, a partir desse cadastro no formulário, posso dar acesso exclusivo à pagina redirecionada?

Comment: Edite a pergunta como eu já disse. PS: talvez sessão somente não resolva teu problema

Comment: Que isso, imagina, agora vou apagar os comentários, já que conseguimos clarear o teu problema e é só aguardar :)

Answer (score 0):

O WordPress tem uma solução nativa que pode te ajudar: **[nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)**. Na verdade nonces são uma funcionalidade de segurança pra evitar ataques **[CSRF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)**, mas acho que podem ser uma solução simples pra você.

Na página do seu formulário, inclua dentro do `<form>` isso:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'nome_da_acao', '_valida_form' ); ?>
```

Essa função vai adicionar um `input[type=hidden]` no seu formulário, contendo um nonce - um valor único e temporário.

Seu formulário vai ser processado em outra página, então no código dessa página, quando receber os dados do formulário, você valida o nonce:

```
<?php
    $request = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST );

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $request['_valida_form'], 'nome_da_acao' ) ) {
        // o nonce não foi reconhecido, então redireciona para a home
        wp_redirect( home_url('/') ); exit();
    }

    // continua o processamento do formulário e exibe a página
```

Documentação:

**[wp_nonce_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/)**

**[wp_verify_nonce()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/)**